# How to find image on whole screen?

Tags: ui-automation, ranorex

Is it possible to click on an image, that is not located in a specific container element?

When I do have a container, I use something like this:

```
MyRepo.AnyForm.AnyElement.Click(new Location(Imaging.Load(anyPicture.bmp)));
```

and that works very well.
But now, I want to click on a menu item inside some context menu that Ranorex is not able to identify. So I want to let Ranorex easily search the whole screen for the target image.
Something like this:

```
AnyElementThatRepresentsTheWholeScreen.Click(new Location(Imaging.Load(anyPicture.bmp)))
```

Thanks and regards,
fachexot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. Here the solution if someone has the same problem:

```
Host.Local.Click(new Location(Imaging.Load(anyPicture.bmp)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have image in GridItem. I am able to find the GridItem and Image.I am not able to Click it from my UI Automation Sample.I am doing it in c++

```
IUIAutomationElement* p1
.......
.......
POINT clickable;
BOOL gotClickable; 
hr = p1->GetClickablePoint(&clickable,&gotClickable);


mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,clickable.x,clickable.y,0,0);
```